# Cuando quiero ingresar un valor numérico de tipo Double me da un error

Tags: java

Éste es mi código:

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        double dolares;
        double colones;

        System.out.println("INGRESE LOS COLONES A CONVERTIR: ");
        colones=sc.nextDouble();

        dolares=0.125*colones;
        System.out.println("Su conversion de Colon a Dolar es: "+dolares);

    }
}
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: ¿Ya lo verificaste bien? Lo probé y no sale ningún error. Asegurate de ingresar "." y no una ",".

Answer (score 0):

Ese código esta bien, mira a ver si estas metiendo los números con una coma en vez de con un punto, si los metes con una coma te dará error.

Por ejemplo:

23,5 Error

23.5 Correcto